# Determine Dask scheduler IP address deploying with Kubernetes

Tags: python, azure, docker, kubernetes, dask

I'm trying to implement in Kubernetes Dask distributed with one scheduler and three workers. I have one pod (`frontend.yaml`) for the scheduler and three other pods (`replicas: 3 in worker.yaml`) for the workers. The problem is that the workers are trying to connect to the scheduler and get a timeout as they don't know the IP address of the scheduler. Since these IP addresses are defined dynamically by Kubernetes I need to understand how this should be configured.

The IP addresses of the scheduler and the workers are determined dynamically:

```
sofer@abc:~/aks$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP          
img-python-6ff4d88876-n97g8   2/2     Running            0          4m42s   10.1.0.34  
worker-5f6d948874-fn67p       1/1     Running            4          4m22s   10.1.0.18  
worker-5f6d948874-hhjs7       0/1     Running            3          4m22s   10.1.0.38  
worker-5f6d948874-jbh4k       1/1     Running            4          4m22s   10.1.0.22
```

frontend.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: img-python
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cont-python
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cont-python
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cont-scheduler
          image: xxx.azurecr.io/img-python-001:latest
          command: ["dask-scheduler"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8786
            - containerPort: 8787
```

worker.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cont-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cont-worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cont-worker
          image: sofacr.azurecr.io/img-python-001:latest
          workingDir: /code
          command: ["dask-worker"]
          args: ["scheduler:8786"]
          env:
            - name: PYTHONPATH
              value: "/code"
            - name: SCHEDULER_ADDRESS
              value: "scheduler"
            - name: SCHEDULER_PORT
              value: "8786"
```

Comment: Have you checked out the [dask](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/dask) and [daskhub](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/daskhub) helm charts? These set up full deployments with [dask_kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org) or [dask-gateway](https://gateway.dask.org/). Rather than manually provisioning workers and specifying the IP address, these deployments create the scheduler and workers dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Michael Delgado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888719/michael-delgado) . Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

You can check the [dask](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/dask) and [daskhub](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/daskhub) helm charts. These set up full deployments with [dask_kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/) or [dask-gateway](https://gateway.dask.org/). Rather than manually provisioning workers and specifying the IP address, these deployments create the scheduler and workers dynamically

As suggested by [ps0604](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362485/ps0604), to deploy dask using the Dask Helm chart, you can refer to [Helm Install Dask for a Single User](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html#kubernetes-helm-single)

Comment: To be more specific, [this is how I deployed the dask helm chart](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html#kubernetes-helm-single)